# INSERT INTO statement contains following unknown field name

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, insert, ms-jet-ace

I’m using Coldfusion 9,0,0,251028 on Windows 7 64-bit, with a Microsoft Access 97 database.

When I run this query:

```
<cfquery name="put_in_info" datasource="#db#">

      insert into news

                  (is_current, display, mes_dat,mes_tim,mes_sub,mes_text,scrollshow,exp_dat)

      values

  (1,1, #createodbcdate(now())#, #createodbctime(now())#, '#subject#', '#message#',1, #session.expdate#)

</cfquery>
```

I get this error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.

[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'exp_dat'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.   The error occurred in H:\Inetpub\pvalert.com\listserver\admin\templates\post_breaking.cfm: line 26
Called from H:\Inetpub\pvalert.com\listserver\admin\new_process.cfm: line 54
Called from H:\Inetpub\pvalert.com\listserver\admin\templates\post_breaking.cfm: line 26
Called from H:\Inetpub\pvalert.com\listserver\admin\new_process.cfm: line 54

24 :      (is_current, display, mes_dat,mes_tim,mes_sub,mes_text,scrollshow,exp_dat)

25 :   values

26 :   (1,1, #createodbcdate(now())#, #createodbctime(now())#, '#subject#', '#message#',1, #session.expdate#)

27 :    </cfquery>

28 :

VENDORERRORCODE


  -1507

SQLSTATE


  HYS22

SQL


   insert into news (is_current, display, mes_dat,mes_tim,mes_sub,mes_text,scrollshow,exp_dat) values (1,1, {d '2011-04-11'}, {t '17:49:09'}, 'Test message - please ignore', 'This is a test message, please ignore. ',1, {ts '2011-05-15 00:00:00'})

DATASOURCE


  rpv_list
```

Exp_dat is an expiration date column in a table that I need to update.

I've tried removing the "session." on the expdate variable, and that did nothing.  Likewise for removing the any spaces around line 24's "exp_dat".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message given doesn't complain about the value inserted. It states that the field "exp_dat" doesn't exist in your table/view "news".

The first thing to do is to double check if there actually is a field named "exp_dat". If you don't have direct access to the database, just fire up a query from within ColdFusion and dump the query result.

```
<cfquery name="getSomeRowsFromNewsTable" datasource="#db#" maxrows="10">
select * from news
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#getSomeRowsFromNewsTable#" abort="true">
```

Maybe someone aliased the field, or did not include an existing field in a view, or it's called "exp_dattim", or ...

Comment: I ran a select statement that gets all rows and then:

<cfdump var="#get_info.columnlist#">

and got:

DISPLAY,**EXP_DAT**,ID,IS_CURRENT,MES_DAT,MES_SUB,MES_TEXT,MES_TIM,SCROLLSHOW 

So it seems that the column does exist

Comment: @BarrettChamberlain your comment is opposed to the v accepting the reply.., Can you tell us what actually solved the problem? Upper/Lower case in field name sensitivity?

Answer (score 2):

Given an INSERT query, such as

```
INSERT INTO tblname ('column1', 'column2', 'column3' ...) VALUES ...
```

Try using square brackets- that's []- around the column names, like so:

```
INSERT INTO tblname ([column1], [column2], [column3] ...) VALUES ...
```

This worked for me in the Access SQL GUI Interpreter, but might not solve the OP's specific situation (Coldfusion, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap every value you insert in your insert statement with single quotes.ie `'#variable#', '#another_var#'` -- and so on. I think I had the same problem, but doing that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issues several times , with MS Access. I know the Column name is spelled correctly and that the column exists. 
E.G., I can do a 'SELECT' on the column with no problem, but when I try a simple SQL INSERT, I get that error:  "... Unknown field name"
I typed nothing, just used copy and paste, so there is no chance of a typo. Access literally does recognize a column name in SELECT statement, and DOES NOT recognize that same column name when attempting an INSERT.

It appears to be a bug in MS Access 2010.

Comment: I can confirm this error in 2007 also. How I got around the error is that I noticed Access would helpfully rename the column in the query designer to what it wanted it to be. If I changed the column name in the table to match that, then the Insert query would run just fine.